# PHP / SQL Server which adapter to use and general questions

Tags: php, sql-server

I beginning a project which requires me to use php with a SQL Server database. Although I am using mySQL for years this will be my first project using SQL Server.

- Is it better to use PDO than MMSQL.
- Are there any "Gotcha"s I should be aware when using SQL Server.
- Does SQL Server have any UTF-8 problems?

Comment: PHP server will run on Windows or Linux?

Comment: PHP will run on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running PHP on windows, I'd use Microsoft's PHP SQL Server "driver":

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/PHP-Driver.aspx

it has the best feature set for SQL Server.

Comment: Well looking a little bit more it seems like SQL Server Driver can be a good choice. And it has very good documentation. Though I'm still considering PDO. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can have BOTH the PHP driver produced by Microsoft AND PDO. The 2.0 version of the Microsoft driver includes a PDO driver. You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=80e44913-24b4-4113-8807-caae6cf2ca05. This whitepaper should get you started: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/whitepaper-accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx.

Hope that helps.

-Brian